# exception EJB is already associated with an incomplete transaction

Tags: transactions, ejb-3.0

**when I invoke list page I get this error ,also program running but some progresses arent working and redirect debug page ,I couldnt fix it ,anybody know this error,what does it mean**

INFO: EJB5018: An exception was thrown during an ejb invocation on [EjbSynchronizations]
INFO: javax.ejb.EJBException: nested exception is: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJB is already associated with an incomplete transaction
java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJB is already associated with an incomplete transaction
 com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
 //**lots of useless error info**

Comment: Provide some information regarding transaction-type used (BMT/CMT), beans (SLSB/SFSB) etc.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that two threads are attempting to call the same stateful session bean instance.  A stateful session bean instance can only be associated with a single transaction (which are per thread) at a time.  Without more information, it's impossible to know what is wrong with the application to make this happen.  One possibility is that the application injects a stateful session bean into a servlet, so all requests on all threads are attempting to use the same instance.  Either each request should create its own instance of the bean, or the bean should actually be stateless.