# Exception: EJB is already associated with an incomplete transaction while sending Messages over JMS API

Tags: java, transactions, jms

I am developing an Application based on the JMS API for the first time and get the following Exception when sending multiple Messages to the same queue. For every Message i use the same connection and Queue Resource and i don't use a separate User Transaction. For every Message, a new Session is created and closed, after the message is sent. The following example shows the method which sends the messages. Does anyone know, what i am doing wrong. The following Post [JMS Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385731/exception-ejb-is-already-associated-with-an-incomplete-transaction) handles a similar problem, but the MessageDriven Bean must not be declared as Stateless. If just one Message is sent, everything works fine. Thanks for any Response

```
@Resource(lookup=NAME_CONNECTION_FACTORY)   
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Resource(lookup=NAME_QUEUE_CALCULATE) 
private Queue queueCalculate;

public void send(Destination destination, List<RequestObject> lstRequestObjectList) throws ExceptionJavaMessageQueue {
    try {
        if(destination == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("message could not be send because of missing destination");
        }
        for(RequestObject currentRequestObject : lstRequestObject) {
            final Session session = this.createSession();
            final MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            ObjectMessage objectMessage = session.createObjectMessage(currentRequestObject);
            producer.send(objectMessage);
            session.close();
        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(super.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "error while sending JMS Message", e);
        throw new ExceptionJavaMessageQueue("error while sending JMS Message");
    }   catch (SecurityException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(super.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "error while sending JMS Message", e);
        throw new ExceptionJavaMessageQueue("error while sending JMS Message");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(super.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "error while sending JMS Message", e);
        throw new ExceptionJavaMessageQueue("error while sending JMS Message");
    } 
}
```

.

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJB is already associated with an incomplete transaction
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2004)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy423.getEntityManager(Unknown Source)
at de.sanctionlist.database.dao.__EJB31_Generated__Database__Intf____Bean__.getEntityManager(Unknown Source)
at de.sanctionlist.database.dao.DataAccessObject.createNamedQuery(DataAccessObject.java:115)
at de.sanctionlist.database.dao.DAOEntityJob.findByCheckId(DAOEntityJob.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor371.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor380.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
... 32 more
```